# Only seeing 1 object out of an array of 3 in XNA

Tags: c#, arrays, xna, draw

Can anyone see where I am going wrong here.

I have a CameraObject class (its not a camera, simply the Model of a box to represent a "camera") that has a Model and a Position. It also has the usual LoadContent(), Draw() and Update() methods.
However, when I draw the array of Models, I only see 1 model on the screen (well, there might be 3 but they might all be in the same location)?

The Draw() method for the CameraModel class looks like this:

```
public void Draw(Matrix view, Matrix projection) 
    { 
        transforms = new Matrix[CameraModel.Bones.Count]; 
        CameraModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms); 

        // Draw the model 
        foreach(ModelMesh myMesh in CameraModel.Meshes) 
        { 
            foreach (BasicEffect myEffect in myMesh.Effects) 
            { 
                myEffect.World = transforms[myMesh.ParentBone.Index]; 
                myEffect.View = view; 
                myEffect.Projection = projection; 

                myEffect.EnableDefaultLighting(); 
                myEffect.SpecularColor = new Vector3(0.25f); 
                myEffect.SpecularPower = 16; 
            } 
            myMesh.Draw(); 
        } 
    }
```

Then in my Game1 class I create an array of CameraObject objects:

```
CameraObject[] cameraObject = new CameraObject[3];
```

Which I Initialize() - so each new object should be at +10 from the previous object

```
for (int i = 0; i < cameraObject.Length; i++) 
        { 
            cameraObject[i] = new CameraObject(); 
            cameraObject[i].Position = new Vector3(i * 10, i * 10, i * 10); 
        }
```

And finally Draw()

```
Matrix view = camera.viewMatrix; 
Matrix projection = camera.projectionMatrix; 

for (int i = 0; i < cameraObject.Length; i++) 
{ 
    cameraObject[i].Draw(view, projection); 
}
```

Where view and projection are from my Camera() class which looks like so:

```
viewMatrix = Matrix.Identity; 
projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f), 16 / 9, .5f, 500f);
```

But I only see 1 object drawn to the screen? I have stepped through the code and all seems well but I cant figure out why I cant see 3 objects?

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong?

This is the code in my Camera() class to UpdateViewMatrix:

```
private void UpdateViewMatrix(Matrix chasedObjectsWorld)
    {
        switch (currentCameraMode)
        {
            case CameraMode.free:
                // To be able to rotate the camera and and not always have it looking at the same point
                // Normalize the cameraRotation’s vectors, as those are the vectors that the camera will rotate around
                cameraRotation.Forward.Normalize();
                cameraRotation.Up.Normalize();
                cameraRotation.Right.Normalize();

                // Multiply the cameraRotation by the Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle() function, 
                // which rotates the matrix around any vector by a certain angle
                // Rotate the matrix around its own vectors so that it works properly no matter how it’s rotated already
                cameraRotation *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(cameraRotation.Right, pitch);
                cameraRotation *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(cameraRotation.Up, yaw);
                cameraRotation *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(cameraRotation.Forward, roll);

                // After the matrix is rotated, the yaw, pitch, and roll values are set back to zero
                yaw = 0.0f;
                pitch = 0.0f;
                roll = 0.0f;

                // The target is changed to accommodate the rotation matrix
                // It is set at the camera’s position, and then cameraRotation’s forward vector is added to it
                // This ensures that the camera is always looking in the direction of the forward vector, no matter how it’s rotated
                target = Position + cameraRotation.Forward;

                break;

            case CameraMode.chase:
                // Normalize the rotation matrix’s forward vector because we’ll be using that vector to roll around
                cameraRotation.Forward.Normalize();
                chasedObjectsWorld.Right.Normalize();
                chasedObjectsWorld.Up.Normalize();

                cameraRotation = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(cameraRotation.Forward, roll);

                // Each frame, desiredTarget will be set to the position of whatever object we’re chasing
                // Then set the actual target equal to the desiredTarget, can then change the target’s X and Y coordinates at will
                desiredTarget = chasedObjectsWorld.Translation;
                target = desiredTarget;

                target += chasedObjectsWorld.Right * yaw;
                target += chasedObjectsWorld.Up * pitch;

                // Always want the camera positioned behind the object, 
                // desiredPosition needs to be transformed by the chased object’s world matrix
                desiredPosition = Vector3.Transform(offsetDistance, chasedObjectsWorld);

                // Smooth the camera’s movement and transition the target vector back to the desired target
                Position = Vector3.SmoothStep(Position, desiredPosition, .15f);

                yaw = MathHelper.SmoothStep(yaw, 0f, .1f);
                pitch = MathHelper.SmoothStep(pitch, 0f, .1f);
                roll = MathHelper.SmoothStep(roll, 0f, .1f);

                break;

            case CameraMode.orbit:
                // Normalizing the rotation matrix’s forward vector, and then cameraRotation is calculated
                cameraRotation.Forward.Normalize();

                //  Instead of yawing and pitching over cameraRotation’s vectors, we yaw and pitch over the world axes
                // By rotating over world axes instead of local axes, the orbiting effect is achieved
                cameraRotation = Matrix.CreateRotationX(pitch) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(yaw) * Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(cameraRotation.Forward, roll);

                desiredPosition = Vector3.Transform(offsetDistance, cameraRotation);
                desiredPosition += chasedObjectsWorld.Translation;
                Position = desiredPosition;

                target = chasedObjectsWorld.Translation;

                roll = MathHelper.SmoothStep(roll, 0f, .2f);

                break;
        }

        // Use this line of code to set up the View Matrix
        // Calculate the view matrix
        // The up vector is based on how the camera is rotated and not off the standard Vector3.Up
        // The view matrix needs an up vector to fully orient itself in 3D space, otherwise,
        // the camera would have no way of knowing whether or not it’s upside-down
        viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(Position, target, cameraRotation.Up);
    }
```

Comment: What is the position of the camera? Try varying only the x-position of the created objects and moving your camera back.

Comment: Ok Ill try that. The camera is at: Position = new Vector3(0, 10, 70);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing in your code where your cameraObject[n].Position (which is probably the only thing that uniquely differentiates the position between the three models) is affecting the effect.World property.

```
effect.World = transforms[myMesh.ParentBone.Index];
```

does not typically take individual model position into account.

Try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cameraObject.Length; i++) 
{ 
    cameraObject[i].Draw(view, projection, cameraObject[i].Position); 
} 


//later in the draw method
public void Draw(Matrix view, Matrix projection, Vector3 pos)
{
  // ...
  myEffect.World = transforms[myMesh.ParentBone.Index] * Matrix.CreateTranslation(pos);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Yip, that was exactly my problem. Thanks a million for the help Steve

Answer (score 0):

CameraObject[1] & [2] are located at a greater positive Z value than camera[0] and the view matrix is located at the origin & looking in a negative Z direction (remember, the view matrix is the inverted equivalent of a world matrix).
Instead of setting your viewMatrix to Matrix.Identity, set it to this and you might see all three:

```
viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0,0,75), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
```

Comment: Yeah tried that but no luck sorry. See edit of my post above, I have included my Camera() class  UpdateViewMatrix() method. Should really have included it first time around sorry